# Any alternate way to implement the peek method?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am learning data structures on my own and have been trying to implement them using Java. Currently I am attempting to implement a array based stack. In the `peek` method when the stack is empty I am currently catching `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and then returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to stop the program from quitting and getting it ready for further push operations. Is there any other way to implement the `peek` method so that it just prints the message inside the `catch` block without returning the Integer.MIN_VALUE.

```
public class Stack {
    int[] arr;
    int top = -1;
    int currSize = 10;

    /* Constructor */
    public Stack() {
        arr = new int[10];
    }

    public void push(int data) {
        if (top ==  arr.length - 1) {
            resize();
        }
        top++;
        arr[top] = data;
    }

    /*
    public void pop() {
        arr[top] = 0;
        top--;
    }
    */

    public int peek() {
        try {
            return arr[top];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        }
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    /* Resizes the array when space runs out */
    public void resize() {
        int[] newArr = new int[2 * currSize];
        currSize = 2 * currSize;
        for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length / 2; i++) {
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        arr = newArr;
        newArr = null;
    }

    /* Show elements in stack */
    public void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " -> ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /* Rturn the no of elements in stack */
    public int getSize() {
        return top + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack st = new Stack();
        System.out.println(st.peek());
    }
}
```

I tried omitting the `Integer.MIN_VALUE` return statement but the program wouldn't compile.

I was expecting that after the message in `catch` block had been printed the control would return from the `peek` method to the `main` method and resume executing the other statements in main method (probably any push operations).

A solution which occurs to me is the I change the `peek` method return type to void, print the top most value and the return `null` but I don't want to take this path because I may want to store the return value and use it in some other parts of program.

Comment: If your method is declared to return something, you must return something (or throw an exception; a special kind of "return value"). `peek` without returning anything doesn't make sense (because then you are not peeking)

Comment: Within the exception code block: `System.out.println("Stack is empty"); return top;`. Remove the `return Integer.MIN_VALUE;` line.

Comment: It would be better to let it throw the exception. The caller needs to know there was nothing there, as opposed to Integer.MIN_VALUE which could be a real value on the stack. But actually if the application calls `peek()` when there is nothing on the stack, that is an application bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Throw an `Exception`. You could simply throw the one you are currently catching.

```
public int peek() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    return arr[top];
}
```

You could return an `Optional<Integer>` like

```
public Optional<Integer> peek() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(arr[top]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Or you could return an `Integer` and make it `null`. Warning, this is possibly a **billion dollar mistake**<sup>1</sup>. Like,

```
public Integer peek() {
    try {
        return arr[top];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");
    }
    return null;
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Null References The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://youtu.be/ybrQvs4x0Ps)</sub>

Comment: I tried as you said
```
public int peek() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        // try {
        //     return arr[top];
        // } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //     System.out.println("Stack is empty");
        // }
        // return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return arr[top];
    }
```
But I get
```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10
 at Stack.peek(Stack.java:33)
 at Stack.main(Stack.java:62)
```

Comment: @paneer_curry Yes. If you aren't returning `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and instead throw an `Exception` then the caller must handle that `Exception` (or it will bubble up to the user). There was no value. An alternative approach is to implement `isEmpty()` or `size()` and then test for `0` before calling the method.

Comment: `OptionalInt` would be more adequate than `Optional<Integer>` IMO

Comment: @user16320675 Perhaps in this example. But really OP should have a generic `Stack`, or call it an `IntStack` or just use `ArrayDeque`.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying; only return a value if there is one, otherwise print a message.

This is where exceptions are actually useful.

Have your method throw an exception, and catch it wherever you are calling the `peek` method.

```java
public int peek() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    return arr[top];
}
```

```java
void example() {
    int value;
    try {
        value = stack.peek();
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
        System.out.println("stack is empty");
    }
}
```

It's a matter of re-ordering and re-thinking your control-flow.
Which for a situation like this, is typically at ground-level, and easy to implement.